# In place update of objects in a static list using lambdas

Tags: arraylist, lambda, java-8

I am having a static list object which has objects of type User. The User is having a list of Filters. The idea is to update the List object in place without creating a new list.

```
public class User implements Entity {

    public User() {
    }

    private String userName;
    private String userId;
    private List<Filter> filters;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<Filter> getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(List<Filter> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

}

public class Filter {

    private String name;
    private FilterValue value;
    private String type;
    private boolean encrypted;
    private boolean readOnly;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date modifiedOn;
    private boolean valid;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public FilterValue getFilterValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setFilterValue(FilterValue value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isEncrypted() {
        return encrypted;
    }

    public void setEncrypted(boolean encrypted) {
        this.encrypted = encrypted;
    }

    public boolean isReadOnly() {
        return readOnly;
    }

    public void setReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
        this.readOnly = readOnly;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Date getModifiedOn() {
        return modifiedOn;
    }

    public void setModifiedOn(Date modifiedOn) {
        this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

I have a method to update the users as well as the corresponding filters associated. The method becomes very clumsy as i nest through the list of filters. Is there anyway i could do the updating of the filter list elements easily.

```
private static List<User> users;

@Override
public void update(User item) {
    users.forEach(element -> {
        if(element.getUserId() == item.getUserId()){
           element.setUserId(item.getUserId());
           element.setUserName(item.getUserName());
           element.getFilters().forEach(filter -> {
               Set<String> filters = item.getFilters().stream().map(f -> f.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
               List<Filter> present = item.getFilters().stream().filter(x -> filters.contains(x.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
               List<Filter> notPresent = item.getFilters().stream().filter(x -> !filters.contains(x.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
               if(present.isEmpty()){
                   element.setFilters(item.getFilters());
               }else {
                   element.getFilters().stream().forEach(filt -> {
                       present.stream().forEach(x -> {
                           if(filt.getName() == x.getName()){
                               filt.setName(x.getName());
                               filt.setFilterValue(x.getFilterValue());
                               filt.setCreatedOn(x.getCreatedOn());
                               filt.setModifiedOn(x.getModifiedOn());
                               filt.setEnabled(x.isEnabled());
                               filt.setEncrypted(x.isEncrypted());
                               filt.setReadOnly(x.isReadOnly());
                               filt.setType(x.getType());
                               filt.setValid(x.isValid());
                               filt.setDescription(x.getDescription());
                           }
                       });
                   });
               }

               if(!notPresent.isEmpty()){

               }
           });
        }
    });
}
```

This looks horribly bloated.

Comment: you could at least merge `present` and `notPresent` via `partitioningBy` I guess

Comment: also some ``if's`` can be replaced with ``filter``. Other than that you could extract some operations into separate methods

Comment: As a starting point, there is no sense in statements like `if(element.getUserId() == item.getUserId()){ element.setUserId(item.getUserId()); … ` or `if(filt.getName() == x.getName()){ filt.setName(x.getName()); …`. Further, you should consider using `Map`s instead of nested loops with comparison. That would also eliminate the broken string comparison via `==`…

Comment: Why aren't `User` and `Filter` implementing the `equals` and `hashCode` methods? Everything would become far way easier then.

Comment: Besides, can there be more than one user in the `users` list with the same `userId`? Same for filters... can a user have more than one filter with the same name?

Comment: @Federico No , users and filters are unique entries. There cannot be any duplicates.